# Tags: Jurisprudence vs. Philosophy of Law

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I would like to have a [philosophy-of-law](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-law) tag. Firstly, I think that [jurisprudence](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jurisprudence) and philosophy of law aren't nearly the same thing (I could elaborate on this, but I doubt anyone would be interested in my arguments). Secondly, jurisprudence isn't a philosophical branch while philosophy of law is, and if jurisprudence is a philosophical topic, then it's discussed by philosophy of law. Therefore, if we, for economic reasons, can have only one of the two, I would prefer having the philosophy-of-law tag.

Comment: Concur -- are there any particular questions that you think should be tagged?

Comment: Ah, sorry. You're calling for "jurisprudence" to be made a synonym of "philosophy-of-law". Let me take a look at the tag first, but that sounds eminently reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[philosophy-of-law](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-law) is now the master synonym for [jurisprudence](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jurisprudence). The eleven questions involved have been retagged appropriately.

Comment: Cool. Thank you, @Joseph